# typo in advertiser's ad

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, advertising

http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx

"We a unique opportunity to promote your brand"...

Doesn't read right.

Comment: Looks like the **offer** has been removed.

Comment: Actually, it's far worse than a typo: it's a terrible attempt at ebonics.  Cue the "that's racist" kid.

Comment: I really hope you are right Pesto.

Answer (score 4):

I accidently a word.

«fixed»