# It is currently possible to notify all users in a room

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, highlighting

My [self-censoring](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/157133/history) attempt ended up highlighting for the whole room.

Apparently, most combinations of three or more non-letters after the @ symbol will work, including the original `@#$£` or less imaginative  `@###`, `@$$$`, `@£££`. `@@@@` also works.

Comment: It is at moments like this when I wish I could make posts private to just the mod team.

Comment: @badp We've not exactly kept it a secret in the tavern :)

Comment: @@@@ Good point.

Comment: If you need to report something privately you could email them (team@stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Simon, see Grace Note's [excellent answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/are-typo-notices-appropriate-for-meta/56450#56450) to my question about bug reports

Comment: @badp, there's a significant typo in your title; I believe you meant to write " [About your @***ing chatroom.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website) "

Comment: This even alerts people in _other_ rooms too. I thought I was going crazy hearing the notification sound, but not seeing any new messages in any room I was in.

Comment: @Popular: Any other way of reporting private bugs would have that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one to trigger this bug actually was our [CEO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), with his very eloquent utterance

> @!#$%^&*()_(*&^%$#@!@#$%^&*()(*&^$%#@!#$%^&*()(*&^%$#@!

Fixed now, thanks :)