# What is the maximum number of users that can be pinged in chat on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

What is the maximum number of @somenamehere that I can use in a single chat message to ping people? Asking out of curiosity rather than any practical standpoint as I can't envision needing more than a few.

Comment: Time was, you could just [notify everyone](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=157156#157156) with a single `@`....

Comment: @DanielBeck the link I posted was Shog commenting on an early, and long since fixed, chat bug. Once upon a time, if you posted `@!!!` or `@@@@` or similar messages, it would global-ping everyone.

Comment: @pop thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Further reference: [It is currently possible to notify all users in a room](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63485)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## What is the maximum number of users that *you* can ping?

In all seriousness, there doesn't seem to be one, at least for me.  The only real limitation is your patience and your typing speed. And the amount of flesh left on your fingers after you've typed that many keystrokes.

On a side note, please don't support the fool that invented @@@@ and @## though. They used to work, and by now probably have a replacement (unforuanately). Ping grenadiers are not amusing.

Comment: usign tab-completion might help... also there is a limitation given by the users **currently** in the room. anything else is mod-power (superping ftw)