# Spelling error/typo in the SO 10k tools page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, spelling

The SO 10k tools page has a typo under the `close` tab: it reads “Recent occurences” where it should instead be correctly spelled "occurrences", with two r’s not just one.

Sorry to bug you with such a trivial bug report, but [this posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/are-typo-notices-appropriate-for-meta) suggested it was ok, and I didn’t find any other way to flag it as needing attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: U has meny spelin erurs]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/funny-pictures-cat-proofreads-your-essays.jpg))</sub>

Fixed in the next build; thanks!

Comment: +1 despite the picture being of a cat and not a unicorn.

Comment: LOLcorns -- I smell a bizniss model.