# Typo in "Access to moderator tools" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

In the *Access to moderator tools* article located at https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools the term "casted" is incorrectly used as the past form of "cast."

I didn't see any other note on this and am assuming this is the appropriate venue based on the post at [Are typo notices appropriate for Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/are-typo-notices-appropriate-for-meta).

Comment: Glad I searched.  I was just about to post the same bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed on the Meta Stack Overflow version of the privileges page. It will eventually be pushed out to all other sites.